# Making text hover in TileMill?

Tags: tilemill

In Tilemill, I have a #layer that consists of a CSV with 3 columns: [Name], [Latitude], and [Longitude].

I have plotted points using the latitude and longitude, but I would like to have the Name of each point only to be visible when it is hovered over.

I am presuming that I will need to write some kind of HTML code in the Templates -> Teaser tab, but am unsure of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

Interaction of that sort is not possible in TileMill.  The reason for this is that TileMill generates static .png images of your map as 256x256px tiles.  To re-render markers, you would have to generate (and serve) a new tile every time a user hovered over the marker--or generate multiple tiles if the marker overlapped many.

It *is* possible to generate popup interaction in TileMill using [UTF-8Grids](https://www.mapbox.com/blog/how-interactivity-works-utfgrid/), in the `Templates -> Teaser` tab as you mentioned, but that interaction will only display a popup, not change the style of the marker.

To pull off what you're talking about, you would need to use a javascript library like [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html) or [mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.0/).